# NoClassDefFoundError exception while running basic Groovy script from console

Tags: groovy, java-9

I'm getting below exception while running basic groovy script from console
after installation. For installation I have used the installer:

Java version: jdk-9.0.1  , jre-9.0.1

Exception thrown

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovy.xml.jaxb.JaxbGroovyMethods due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/Marshaller

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: Please show the script which is leading to above error?

Comment: Have you installed Groovy? It doesn't come as part of the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Java 9 doesn't package the 'javax.xml' by default. Add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to your command line argument when running.

See [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)